# How to serialize ImportXML followed by QueryDef::Execute

Tags: ms-access

In a block of VBA code, I have a [`Application.ImportXML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.importxml) statement which populates two tables on my SQL server instance (through an MSODBCSQL17 connection, if it matters). This works well.

Then I am willing to perform update queries against [a SQL view of] the same table. I have designed the Access query (`QueryDef`) which is also working correctly when launched individually with its associated parameter.

However when I am trying to run it in VBA using the following code, the update query turns empty, as if the `ImportXML` statement has not yet occurred.

```vb
    Application.ImportXML DataSource:=SomeStructuredXMLfile, ImportOptions:=acAppendData

    With Application.CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyUpdateQuery")
        .Parameters("[parm]") = ValueForParm
        .Execute
        Debug.Print .RecordsAffected
    End With
```

I get the impression things occur as if the transaction around `ImportXML` has not been committed when Access moves on to begin the transaction around the `QueryDef.Execute` statement. However I do not know how to force that first transaction to be committed, i.e. serializing correctly the two operations. Any hint?

Comment: Try throwing a `DoEvents` after `Application.ImportXML`. That allows Access to process any events that have occurred. This might also be a multiple ODBC connections problem, those are often really hard to debug and solve.

Comment: @ErikA: That I have already tried. Without success. Which makes sense since Windows does not have much to say here, the game is between Access, ODBC and the SQL Server instance.